# Get FPS and GPU of an android game using ADB Commands

Tags: java, android

I use adb command **shell dumpsys gfxinfo " + packageName + " framestats"** to get the current view's fps data and everything works fine for few games but however, for few other games, this command doesn't work. It only gives me output as **null** and nothing else. Is there a valid way to get android fps and gpu via adb command?

I tried **adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --latency** and the result kept the same. If there are any updations in the ADB commands please let me know.